# Is it possible to get innerHTML of a website?

Tags: php

I want to get inner HTML of a website using PHP, is it possible?

I only know about `file_get_contents($URL)` method for getting the source.

Comment: innerHTML is a method that is generally used for getting the HTML inside an HTML tag. If you want the entire webpage, then file_get_contents() will work. What specifically are you lookign for?

Comment: Presumably something that executes JavaScript as well.

Comment: What do you mean by `innerHTML` what is different from the source?

Comment: I just want texts , that user sees when page loads :)

Comment: @PeeHaa I just want texts , that user sees when page loads :)

Comment: No @MattBall , i dont get why you linked with that PHP Headless Browser xD

Comment: So you _don't_ want the innerHTML? You want just the user-visible text?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `curl` for send HTTP headers and anothe socket params.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Simple HTML Dom to traverse and parse well-formed HTML:

http://sourceforge.net/projects/simplehtmldom/

For example:

```
<?php

include_once('simple_html_dom.php');
$html = file_get_html('http://target.page.com');

// Output the contents of <div id="target-id">
$content = $html->find('div#target-id');
echo $content[0]->plaintext;

// Output the entire page as plaintext
echo $html->plaintext;

?>
```

Documentation can be found here:

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: It is giving errors :/
Does it works for site with not same domain ?

Comment: What errors are you getting? Yes, this will work for a site on a different domain.